# Hibernate audit log of fields' change

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-envers, audit-logging

How can I log the changes of the entity into log files? 
Consider I have `Person` like this.

```
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Column;

@Entity
@Audited
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
// add getters, setters, constructors, equals and hashCode here
}
```

and a code of changing existing `Person`

```
Person p1 = new Person("name-1", "surname-1");
personRepository.save(p1);
Person p2 = personRepository.findOne(1L);
p2.setName("new-name");
personRepository.save(p2);
```

How can I have

- old entity
- new entity
- list of fields changed (some thing like [Diffable](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/Diffable.html)'s result)

In my log file? I know that [envars](https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/) can store changes in db and let me extract them later with `AuditReader` but I like to store changes in Json file to send them to third party applications (like Elastic).

Comment: Must elastic search be updated immediately as part of the current transaction or would you be able to update elastic search in an eventual consistency pattern?

Comment: In an eventual process. Actually I like to log in into a file so LogStash can read it and push into Elastic.

Comment: You question is way too broad. How about you let Envers do its things and then build some JSON representation of the data in the audit tables.

Comment: The thing is that I don't like Envers to put more load on my db. In addition, Envers  force me to query my db to get changes. It means more load on my poor DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom interceptor by implementing `org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor`. This has callbacks to update/insert/delete with old and new snapshots of entities.

Refer [this](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/) article for more details

Comment: Do I have change's there? I just see the entity which should flush to db.

Comment: @mLotfizad Since you have both old and new state, you could calculate diff

Answer (score 3):

I would actually tackle this from two points of view.

One of the benefits you gain by using Envers is the fact you can very quickly annotate your entities and tell the framework exactly how you wish to track the changes for your entity models.  What is even better is you can have Envers generate the diffable fields for you automatically.

Lets take this basic entity:

```
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
public class Person {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
}
```

When you enable the `withModifiedFlag` feature, this informs Envers to add some additional metadata columns to the audit table for this entity, so basically this entity's audit table would look like this:

```
+----+------+----------+-----+---------+
| ID | name | name_MOD | REV | REVTYPE |
+----+------+----------+-----+---------+
```

The benefit here is that if you're using some process to export & stream the data directly from the table, you no longer need to actually diff the current-row against the prior-row to know what changed; the schema tells you this automatically simply by seeing if the associated `_MOD` column is `1` (true) or `0` (false).

From this point you have a couple options.

#### Native Query ETL

You can use Hibernate native queries to extract and transform the data into JSON for ES either via some background application thread or separate background process.  Since the `_MOD` column provides you the indicator that a field changed, you can easily read the rows and build the data necessary without having to perform the diff operation at extract time.

I would also recommend configuring Envers to place the audit objects in a separate catalog/schema.  This maximizes the database's ability to improve disk IO across multiple databases simultaneously.

#### Debezium ETL

The Debezium project is an excellent way to handle data replication.  One of its strong benefits is that it enables users to do this across heterogeneous platforms which fits precisely into your model.

The big difference here is that Debezium does not read the database directly to determine changes, but rather reads the database transaction log file and generates a series of events that describes the DML operations that took place against that database.  In short, you avoid the read operations you are so concerned about since Debezium rehydrates the state directly from the transaction log.

As an example:

1. Hibernate executes `INSERT INTO Person (?,?) VALUES (?,?)`.
2. Hibernate Envers executes `INSERT INTO Person_AUD (...) VALUES (....)`
3. Database writes that operation to the redo/transaction logs.
4. Debezium notices the log was written, reads the entries.
5. Debezium generates an insert-event for `Person_AUD` (table subscribed to).
6. Any registered interested party of that event receives it and processes it.

It is in (5) where your transform/load code would exist to receive that insert event and generate a JSON output and send it to ES.

#### Wrap-up

By using Debezium, you are able to effectively *offline* replicate the data across heterogeneous environments in an extremely efficient manor.  Not only is the project great for your use case, but its extremely valuable in today's modern world of micro-service architecture where data-sharing between services is crucial.

By using Envers, you able able to provide an *online* fallback solution for giving users audit historical data when your ES cluster is unavailable or overloaded rather than giving users a "Service unavailable, come back later" response.

Whatever you decide, performance is not the only concerning factor.  You should also be mindful of the user experience, scalability, and reliability too; hence why I believe the optimal solution is to pair both.

Comment: I like your idea, I've used Debezium in old projects. but, currently, I can't add new technologies to the stack of the project. The definition of the task vividly forced me to log the differences in a log file.